# How to compute for a sequence for a given value in wolfram?

Tags: wolfram-alpha

What would be the correct input in the wolfram website to give u(n) for a given n, where u is a sequence ?

Something like:

```
evaluate [u(n+1)=27*u(n)-14, u(0) = 1] at n = 3
```

Comment: Welcome to MSE!

Comment: Most of the work can be done with
"
recurrance a_(n+1) = 27*a_(n)-14 "

Comment: Entering "a(0)=1, a(n+1) = 27*a(n)-14" outputs a closed form and first nine values. You can enter the closed form and specify n if you want other values "n=3, 1/13 (7 + 2 3^(1 + 3 n))".

Comment: @MattiP. @ Vepir I had figured that out, but then 2 steps are required. I want to be able to change u(0) quickly, in one step... Is that not possible ?

Comment: There is a [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JairTaylor I gave my answer to OP's question here - but I'm not sure If I understand the "wolfram-alpha" tag on this site. What is the borderline between wolfram-alpha queries and Mathematica interpreted (related) queries?

Comment: @vepir Not sure myself.  Just thought the other site might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments already discussed how you can manipulate the recurrence. - But if you are not satisfied with that, why not use the Mathematica cloud interpreter in the wolfram lab?

> - There are two ways to do this. The direct one is to open the code of your wolfram query:

$1.$

[image]

$2.$

> - Which will lead you to the [computable notebook](http://www.wolfram.com/wolframalpha-opencode-tour/), and after you scroll down a bit, you'll find the code:

[image]

$3.$

> - Where for example I told it to get me the terms from $4$th to $6$th. After running that code section (Either clicking Run or pressing Shift + Enter), you will get your results instantly:

[image]

**What if "Open code" is not available?**

However, if you can't directly open the code of your wolfram query, you can go and open a new notebook and paste that code there.

You navigate to [programming lab](https://www.wolfram.com/programming-lab/) and click "[Start programming now](https://www.open.wolframcloud.com/env/wpl/GetStarted.nb?funnel=WPLExplorations#sidebar=explorations)". Then click **File** and **New notebook**.

Click on (+) sign and select "Wolfram language input". Now type in the code from the lab:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[0] == 1, a[1 + n] == -14 + 27 a[n]}, a, {n, 4, 6}]
```

Modify the `{n, 4, 6}` part to list the terms you want, and the `{a[0] == 1, a[1 + n] == -14 + 27 a[n]}` part to setup your recurrence.

Then either click the gear icon on the right and select "Evaluate", or press Shift+Enter.

You'll get your output:

```
{245281,6622573,178809457}
```

Bonus points, if you want to quickly change the starting condition, you can make a table:

**A code snippet to help with your example**

You can use the following code:

```
ClearAll[recurrence,a]
recurrenceName = a;
recurrence[x_] := {a[0] == x, a[1 + n] == -14 + 27 a[n]}
a0min = 0;
a0max = 3;
nmin = 0;
nmax = 5;
Grid[Prepend[Transpose[Prepend[Transpose[Table[RecurrenceTable[recurrence[x], recurrenceName, {n, nmin, nmax}],{x,a0min,a0max}]],Table[StringForm["a(0) = ``", a],{a,a0min,a0max}]]],Table[If[n<nmin,"",StringForm["n = ``", n]],{n,nmin-1,nmax}]],Frame->All]
```

To instantly generate a table for all values you need:

[image]